# Problema al Iniciar la Depuración en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tengo una Aplicacion `Web MVC5` que estoy desarrollando en `Visual Studio 2015 Update 1`, y desde que apliqué la actualización se viene presentando un problema en la depuración.

Al iniciar la depuración el proceso funciona correctamente, pero si debo detener la depuración (corregir algún error, implementar alguna nueva funcionalidad) y vuelvo y ejecuto la depuración no carga el Sitio web ( he probado `Edge`, `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE`) y se queda "Cargando..."

la Imagen de la consola de salida es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuré en `Herramientas` > `Opciones` > Depuración la redirección y carga de los Simbolos en otra carpeta, deshabilité el Intellitrace, Borré la Carpeta IISExpress de Documentos y lo único que hace volver a funcionar la depuración en Cerrar Visual Studio y volver a iniciar.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Ya que usas iisexpress has intentado matando solo el proceso del iisexpress en lugar de todo el visual studio?

Comment: Que version de IISExpress estas utilizando? intentaste actualizarlo. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264   Si creas en el VS2015 un proyecto asp.net mvc nuevo, algo bien simple, y realizas los mismo pasos, sucede los mismo ? Que version de Windows estas utilizando ?

Comment: Has intentado ejecutar el Visual Studio como administrador?

Comment: 1. matar el proceso si funciona.
2. Re-instalar IISExpress no funciona
3. Ejecutar como Administrador no funciona

Comment: Es necesario correr el Visual Studio con permisos de Administrador, eso solucionó mi problema.

Comment: El error que me sale a mí es que yo inicie el proyecto en VS 2017 por lo tanto ya no es compatible con el 2015, pero en el 2017 compila muy bien.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que recomendaria es que cambies el servidor web que defines en el proyecto.

Para llegar a la opción realiza boton derecho del mouse sobre el proyecto web en el solution explorer y en el menu que se desplega la último item dice `Properties`, esto deplegara varias solapas, ve a la que dice `Web` como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrias intentar dejar de usar el IIS Express si es que este trae problemas y pasa a usar el IIS Local, por supeusto tendras que haberlo habilitado en Windows (recuerda validar las [Windows Features](http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-gas-manual-html/gas-topics/Images/IIS_Windows7_CP_WindowsFeatures.jpg))

Se que esto no soluciona el problema con el IIS Express, pero al menos al cambiar de servidor web quizas se resuelva el problema de lo breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso el error lo estaba generando el pool (grupo) de aplicaciones del default web site en el IIS, recientemente había cambiado la clave de dominio y no la había actualizado en el IIS, por esto el pool estaba detenido. Después de actualizar la clave pude hacer debug del proyecto sin ningún problema.
Para saber como se cambia la identidad del pool revisa los pasos del 1 al 6 en este [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSZRWV_9.1.3/com.ibm.dc.install.doc/dctmw000-cs_only.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No he encontrado la forma de corregir el problema, sin embargo se pueden implementar cambios como el sugerido de usar el Local IIS.

Para mi la opción que tomé fue tener una consola de comandos abierta y ejecuto cada vez que termino la sesión de depuración el comando: `tskill iisexpress -t`

Le he seguido la pista a este problema en varios foros y aún no tiene una corrección, esperemos que el Equipo de Visual Studio saque un update para esta funcionalidad.

Comment: una vez me paso que un bloque del disco duro no andaba bien, tenía información y que necesitaba ser leído. Una defragmentada ayudo a solucionar ese problema. Ha salido el Update 2, espero que con ello se haya solucionado tu problema. Saludos